# Is module.exports = { fn } same as exports.fn = fn

Tags: javascript, typescript

For job test i need to create library like this:

```
// do-it.js
function doIt(smth) {}

module.exports = {
    doIt,
};
```

But i'm working with typescript and compiled do-it.ts file looks like this:

```
// do-it.js when compiled from do-it.ts
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.doIt= exports.another = void 0;

function doIt(smth) {}
exports.doIt = doIt;

function another() {}
exports.another= another;
```

Is exports from this two examples will work the same?

Comment: Where did `writePathToFile` come from?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated question, it's another fn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, yes; certainly the resulting exports are the same.

I mean, if you did:

```
module.exports = {
    doIt,
};
```

and later did

```
module.exports = {
    doSomethingElse,
};
```

you'd have a problem, because the second one completesly replaces the previous `exports` object.

You don't need to create that object at all, it's created for you before your module is called. So really, you can just do

```
exports.doIt = doIt;
```

and then

```
exports.doSomethingElse = doSomethingElse;
```

in the first place.

Comment: Although here in 2021, I would advocate using JavaScript standard module syntax rather than CommonJS. If you're using Node.js (as I suspect you are), [details here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Comment: will another function be a problem? Updatet question

Comment: @ZiiMakc - Not at all, just don't overwrite the `exports` object each time.